# app is not launching by itself

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not getting app launching automatically when running in android studio after successful build ,app is installing in mobile i have to open it manually and log-cat messages also not displaying

1. Developer options are enabled
2. USB debugging is enabled
3. Tested it on both Ubuntu 15.04 and window 8
4. Other handsets (Motorola,Xiaoping) are showing logs in lolcat.
5. Tested with different apps but problem only arises on Note 3
   Lite.
6. Android Studio version is 2.1.2
7. Note 3 Lite running on cool-pad official android 5.1

Comment: Is your Note3 detecting in Android Studio?

Comment: yes its detecting and installing also happened..

Comment: Check Settings You should enable Allow Installation from unknown resources.
And also Check in Blocked List is Your app added in blocked list. If so remove it from blocked list

Comment: Installation from unknown resources is already enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately coolpad not allow to auto launch app while debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Check these following steps in your phone

> 1.Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if it's listed.
>
> 2.Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check the Unknown Sources option.
>
> 3.Finally go to Settings -> Developer options: Check the Install via USB option.